# Disable particular CSS style

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm looking for solution, how to disable particular stylesheet, that is used by webpage.

For example:
There is a website that use 4 CSS files (external), and 2 internal style sheets defined within  tags. I would like to be able to turn on or off any of these styles, either external or internal.

Please do you know any tool for any browser that alows me such feature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For testing purpose, programmatically, though browser? how you want to disable it?

Comment: I'm looking for solution using browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can user fierbug or IE Tool bar for this if you want to test online.

E.g Fir bug looks like following [image]

you can make temporary changes as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm looking for tool, that can completely disable whole stylesheet. I don't want to make partial changes to it.

Comment: Do you have code for those pages....?? you can do using browser but can not do for specific css...

Answer (score 0):

I think inline styles has highest precedence so specify none for the properties in inline block to disable css for that particular element